# hd video player for mac

Tags: macos, mediaplayer

I just saw that VLC doesn't support 10-bit yet (i checked the link here and i don't see a 1.2 build) http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=94686

Is there any other good player that supports this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in the link you provide indicate the latest vlc-git nightly release should work with 10-bit mkv files.

On the [VLC nightly build page](http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/macosx-intel/?C=M;O=D), look for the first file with a file name that starts with "vlc-git-intel" or "vlc-git-intel64". Download the former if you want the 32-bit version, the latter for 64-bit. (Even though the vlc-git files don't indicate their version number in the file name, the latest nightly build, as of 10/6/11, is a version 1.2 build)

Be aware these are considered unstable versions, so you may come across unexpected bugs while using the software.

You could also try [MplayerX](http://mplayerx.org/), which I think should support 10-bit video.